# SQL - How do you select the count of foreign key items where there might be none?

Tags: sql

I want to count the number of records linked by a foreign key, however if I use COUNT and INNER JOIN then it won't list it when there are zero.

Table: Questions

- QuestionId (primary key)
- Question Text

Table: Answers

- QuestionId (foreign key)
- AnswerId
- AnswerText

I want to see the count of answers for each question, even if there are zero. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do it without using a join at all

```
select q.questionid, 
  (Select count(*) From answers 
   Where questionid = q.questionid) num_answers
from questions q
```

(internally, the query processor is still doing a join of course.)

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an outer join:

```
select q.questionid, count(a.questionid) as num_answers
from questions q
  left join answers a on a.questionid = q.questionid
group by q.questionid;
```